# Initialize **char array with known size in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I want to initialize an array of strings such that the object is the type **char.

I know that I can do this via:

```
char **my_array = malloc( 3 * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < (3); i++) {
   my_array[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
}

sprintf(my_array[0], "first");
sprintf(my_array[1], "second");
sprintf(my_array[2], "third");
```

But it seems really cumbersome, especially because the strings are set before I compile. Is there a way to get (specifically a char ** type) with syntax more like:

```
char ** my_array = {"first", "second", "third"};
```

So that I have the property:  `printf(my_array[0]);` returns `first`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the strings are fixed, you want an array of `const char *`:

```
const char *my_array[] = {"first", "second", "third"};
```

Comment: Will I be able to pass this to functions that take type char**?

Comment: @shouriha If you mean `char **` then yes, since an array decays to a pointer to its first element when passed to a function.

Answer (score 0):

`char ** my_array` is a pointer to a char pointer, it does not allocate any more memory. If you know from the beginning that you will have only three strings, and expect only strings of max 10 characters, you can allocate your array statically:
`char my_array[3][10]`